# Launch IPad App from another app like email/web browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

How can I launch my IPad app from another native IPad app such as email or web browser. I am pretty new to objective C. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is what's called a `Custom URL Scheme` for your App. You can find more information and a great write up on how to accomplish this here:

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: Lol @rokjarc, luck of the draw ! :)

Comment: +1 for naming the technique correctly and pointing at an example

Comment: This link is outdated